# After adding a Java library module I get : Error: ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android

I just added a java library module in my project in order to split my big project in small one.

my module gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile('com.pubnub:pubnub-gson:4.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    }
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

And I simply add it to my main project :

`compile project(path: ':mymodule')`

my settings.gradle :

```
include ':app', ':mymodule'
```

But when I compile I got :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForQaDebug'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)
```

full stacktrace :

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForQaDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessInfoBuilder$JavaProcessInfoImpl.getExecutable(ProcessInfoBuilder.java:349)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:74)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:49)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.createMainDexList(AndroidBuilder.java:1426)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MultiDexTransform.callDx(MultiDexTransform.java:309)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MultiDexTransform.computeList(MultiDexTransform.java:265)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MultiDexTransform.transform(MultiDexTransform.java:186)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:178)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:174)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:156)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:158)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:118)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 14 more
```

- buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
- multiDexEnabled true
- classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from the

`sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"`

indeed we have to target `1.7` OR simply add retrolambda `apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'` in order to use java 8 in the module